# How can I implement memoize method on an async function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, implementation, memoization

I have been trying to write the implementation of the memoize function in JavaScript. I was asked this in an interview question and haven't been able to put it out of my mind since. I would really appreciate some help with this.

Given a function in which we are making an API call -

```
function getSomeData(foo, callback) {
  var uri = 'http://localhost?foo=' + foo ;
  someAPIUri(uri, function onResponse(error, response, body) {
    callback(error, body);
  });
}
```

Instead of using an API, using setTimeout for async functionality -

```
function getSomeData(foo, callback) {
  setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log('async request');
    callback(2 * foo);
  }, 1000);
}
```

If we make a call like below twice, that means two async calls made, so we need to create a memoize function which caches the response for some input and respond with that in any subsequent call.

```
getSomeData(1, (response) => {
  console.log('getSomeData', response);
})
```

I wrote this function -

```
function memoize(fn) {
  const cache = {};

  return async function() {
    const args = JSON.stringify(arguments);

    console.log('arguments passed to memoize fn: ', args);
    console.log('cache data: ', cache[args]);

    cache[args] = cache[args] || fn.apply(undefined, arguments);
    return cache[args]
  }
}

const memoizedGetSomeData = memoize(getSomeData);

const callback_fn = (response) => {
  console.log('callback response: ', response);
}

memoizedGetSomeData(1, callback_fn);

memoizedGetSomeData(1, callback_fn);
```

This is not working as the async call is getting made for each `memoizedGetSomeData` call.

I would really appreciate some input to get it working and improving my understanding.

This is a codepen of the code - [link](https://codepen.io/wintryleo/pen/WNpdqXJ)

The console log:

```
"arguments passed to memoize fn: " "{'0':1}"
"cache data: " undefined
"arguments passed to memoize fn: " "{'0':1}"
"cache data: " undefined
"async request"
"callback response: " 2
"async request"
"callback response: " 2
```

Comment: Use a promise-returning async function, and a bog-standard `memoize` will work :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only real issue (from what I see) is that `getSomeData` is a poor mock of async functionality, as it doesn't return a promise.

```js
function getSomeData(foo, callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(()=> {
          console.log('async request');
          resolve(callback(2 * foo));
      }, 1000);
  });
}

function memoize(fn) {
  const cache = {};
  return async function() {
    const args = JSON.stringify(arguments);

    console.log('arguments passed to memoize fn: ', args);
    console.log('cache data: ', cache);

    cache[args] = cache[args] || fn.apply(undefined, arguments);
    return cache[args]
  }
}

const memoizedGetSomeData = memoize(getSomeData);

const callback_fn = (response) => {
  console.log('callback response: ', response);
}

memoizedGetSomeData(1, callback_fn);
memoizedGetSomeData(1, callback_fn);
```

Comment: What is the need to stringify the arguments? `const args = JSON.stringify(arguments);` . . . the `.apply()` takes an array of arguments anyways, so why not pass it as is?

Comment: If `cache[args]` value is falsey then this memoization won't provide the benefit. Must check if the arg key is in the cache regardless of value stored.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Bergi and @dave for the comments. I understood the problem with my code and how the memoize function should work like for an async function.

This is the final code with a basic implementation of `Memoize` on an async function -

```
function getSomeData(foo, callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      console.log('async request');
      resolve(callback(2 * foo));
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function memoize(fn) {
  const cache = {};

  return async function() {
    const args = JSON.stringify(arguments);
    cache[args] = cache[args] || fn.apply(undefined, arguments);
    return cache[args]
  }
}

const memoizedGetSomeData = memoize(getSomeData);

const callback_fn = (response) => {
  return response;
}

// this should make async call
memoizedGetSomeData(1, callback_fn).then(response => console.log('response from async call: ', response));

// this should return response from the cache
memoizedGetSomeData(1, callback_fn).then(response => console.log('cached response: ', response));

// this should make async call (different argument)
memoizedGetSomeData(4, callback_fn).then(response => console.log('response from async call: ', response));
```

Log:

```
"async request"
"response from async call: " 2
"cached response: " 2
"async request"
"response from async call: " 8
```

I have updated the Codepen code as well.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getSomeData(foo, callback) {
  console.log('inside async call', foo)
  setTimeout(() => callback(foo * Math.random(100)), 1000)
}

function memoize(fn) {
  let cache = {};
  return function() {
    let key = JSON.stringify(arguments);
    if (key in cache) {
      return cache[key];
    } else {
      cache[key] = fn.apply(this, arguments);
      return cache[key];
    }
  };
}

getSomeDatav2 = memoize(getSomeData);

getSomeDatav2(2, (r) => console.log(r));
getSomeDatav2(2, (r) => console.log(r));
getSomeDatav2(2, (r) => console.log(r));
getSomeDatav2(1, (r) => console.log(r));
getSomeDatav2(1, (r) => console.log(r));
getSomeDatav2(3, (r) => console.log(r));
```